# java Producer-Consumer Not always terminating

Tags: java, producer-consumer

I have a system that reads names from a list, calls an external server for a true/false status check and actions those with a true status. the call to the external server take some time so running it all in one thread isn't very efficient.

I am currently trying to implement it as a producer/consumer system where many consumer threads read the names from a list, call the external server, put the valid names in a blocking queue and have a single consumer pick items from the queue and action them. sadly however the system will at times run to completion and will at other times hang indefinitely.
Test code is as follows

```
public class SubscriberTest {
    static Queue<String> subscribed = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
    static BlockingQueue<String> valid = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(100);
    Random rand = new Random();

    public SubscriberTest(int i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            subscribed.add("I love:" + j);
        }
    }

    public SubscriberTest(Queue<String> subs) {
        subscribed = subs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubscriberTest fun = new SubscriberTest(10000);
        System.out.println(subscribed.size());
        ExecutorService producers = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ExecutorService consumers = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Consumer consumer = fun.new Consumer();
        Producer producer = fun.new Producer();
        while (!subscribed.isEmpty()) {
            producers.execute(producer);
            consumers.execute(consumer);
        }
        producers.shutdown();
        consumers.shutdown();
        System.out.println("finally");
    }

    // take names from subscribed and get status
    class Producer implements Runnable {
        public void run() {

            String x = subscribed.poll();
            System.out.println("Producer: " + x + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                if (getStatus(x)) {
                    valid.put(x);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // this is a call to an external server
        private boolean getStatus(String x) {
            return rand.nextBoolean();
        }
    }

    // takes names from valid queue and save them
    class Consumer implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumer: " + valid.take() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Please show me where I go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ExecutorService is a pool of threads with a queue of tasks.  Adding another queue just adds complexity and increases the chance you will do something incorrect.  I suggest you just use the queue already there.

```
public class SubscriberTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService consumers = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        // middle producer
    final ExecutorService producers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                                   Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    // subscribed/original producer.
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000*1000; i++) {
            final String task = "I love:" + i;
            producers.execute(new MidProducer(task, consumers));
        }

        producers.shutdown();
        producers.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        consumers.shutdown();
        System.out.println("finally");
    }


    static class MidProducer implements Runnable {
        private final Random rand = new Random();
        private final String task;
        private final ExecutorService consumers;

        public MidProducer(String task, ExecutorService consumers) {
            this.task = task;
            this.consumers = consumers;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Producer: " + task + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            if (getStatus(task))
                consumers.execute(new Consumer(task));
        }

        private boolean getStatus(String x) {
            return rand.nextBoolean();
        }

    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable {
        private final String task;

        private Consumer(String task) {
            this.task = task;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Consumer: " + task + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Producer: I love: 1 pool-2-thread-2
Producer: I love: 3 pool-2-thread-4
Producer: I love: 2 pool-2-thread-3
Producer: I love: 5 pool-2-thread-2
Producer: I love: 7 pool-2-thread-2
Producer: I love: 4 pool-2-thread-5
Producer: I love: 6 pool-2-thread-6
Producer: I love: 8 pool-2-thread-7
Producer: I love: 10 pool-2-thread-2
Producer: I love: 9 pool-2-thread-5
Producer: I love: 11 pool-2-thread-8
Producer: I love: 12 pool-2-thread-9
Producer: I love: 14 pool-2-thread-10
Producer: I love: 13 pool-2-thread-2
Producer: I love: 16 pool-2-thread-10
Producer: I love: 15 pool-2-thread-11
Producer: I love: 17 pool-2-thread-12
Producer: I love: 20 pool-2-thread-14
Producer: I love: 19 pool-2-thread-10
Producer: I love: 18 pool-2-thread-13
Producer: I love: 0 pool-2-thread-1
Producer: I love: 22 pool-2-thread-12
Producer: I love: 21 pool-2-thread-15
Producer: I love: 25 pool-2-thread-3
Producer: I love: 27 pool-2-thread-12
Producer: I love: 26 pool-2-thread-10
Producer: I love: 24 pool-2-thread-15
Producer: I love: 28 pool-2-thread-1
Producer: I love: 23 pool-2-thread-16
Producer: I love: 31 pool-2-thread-11
Producer: I love: 30 pool-2-thread-16
Producer: I love: 32 pool-2-thread-1
Producer: I love: 36 pool-2-thread-3
Consumer: I love: 2 pool-1-thread-1
```

...

```
Consumer: I love: 9975 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9977 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9978 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9979 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9981 pool-1-thread-1
Producer: I love: 9996 pool-2-thread-16
Consumer: I love: 9984 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9985 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9990 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9992 pool-1-thread-1
Producer: I love: 9997 pool-2-thread-16
Consumer: I love: 9994 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9995 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9996 pool-1-thread-1
Producer: I love: 9998 pool-2-thread-16
Producer: I love: 9999 pool-2-thread-16
Consumer: I love: 9997 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9998 pool-1-thread-1
Consumer: I love: 9999 pool-1-thread-1
finally
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at th code.  I copy pasted the code as it is and consistently get RejectedExecutionExecptions.

Comment: That's because the consumers are being shutdown in the main thread, before the producers have finished.

Comment: Added a fix so the consumers are not shut down before the producers have finished.

Comment: On changing the number of tasks from 10000 to 100000 (and increasing the timeout) the app still fails to terminate.

Comment: That is strange. It does for me with 1000*1000 tasks.  Perhaps its a JVM bug, can you try Java 6 update 25?

Comment: When I wrote this it was on a Linux box and it ran to completion no problem.  However on Windows it hung the machine so bad, I needed to power cycle the box (the window box is 4x more powerful)  The problem was the cache thread pool accepts an unlimited number of threads, more than the box can handle.  If I change it to use fixed size pool it ran just fine.

Comment: used a fixed thread pool instead of cachedthreadpool and got it sorted. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
String x = subscribed.poll();
```

Will return `null` if nothing is available in the queue, which means that you will try to put a `null` onto the 'valid' queue, which will cause a null pointer exception, and that particular thread will exit.  When this happens with all the threads in the pool, the application will hang.

Comment: Theres always non-null stuff in the subscribed queue so subscribed.poll() should always return a valid string (I think).

Comment: nope.  there is a race condition between your `subscribed.isEmpty()` test in the main thread and the actual producer removing an element (in a separate thread).  so, you can generate many more Producers than there are actual elements on your subscribed queue.

Comment: you are right jtalbohn. I have seen an NPE once. I have now put a null check before processing `subscribed.poll()` However the app still hangs even in cases where theres no NPE.